# React Native : Unexpected view type nested under text node

Tags: react-native

I've got this error on Android. Just in case, I use react-native-maps. Do you know what is it from?

[image: error from device]

Comment: Apparently it's trying to build a `<Text>` node, but is not liking one of ours children.

Comment: Exactly @ChrisGeirman, it's bugging when a children value is called : <Text style={styles.text}>{this.props.children}</Text> and sometimes I've put a <View> inside <Text>, when value is equal to zero... My mistake! Thanks!

Comment: Side note: You should post your own answer so others with the same issue will see it (many don't read comments).  Here is how to self-answer: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: how does {this.props.value} throw this error? I'm standing before the same, but have no idea where my error lies. and no - I don't put <View> inside <Text>...

Comment: I've bumped into the same issue, only on Android. I've got no idea what could it be. For me it's not related to maps for sure, but maybe react-native-swipe-cards.

Comment: I hate android, this does not happen in ios

Answer (score 16):

I also got this error when I was conditionally rendering a  element based on the truthiness of a non-boolean value:

```
<View>
  {stringVariable && <Text>{stringVariable}</Text>}
</View>
```

This code gives me the error. However, if I double negate string variable like so:

```
<View>
  {!!stringVariable && <Text>{stringVariable}</Text>}
</View>
```

it works.

Kind of a dumb error on my part, but it took me a while to figure out.

Comment: Any tips why double-negating it works?  It should render the same eh?  I was having a similar problem but thought it was that somehow it was trying to render a blank node and causing an internal error - replacing with a function that returned the fragment worked instead

Comment: @Kevin Double-negating means if the string is "truthy" the part before `&&` will be  `true`. If you just do `{stringVariable && ...` then it will try to render the variable's value in the `View` component. If you don't like double-negating, you could test the string in some other way, e.g. `stringVariable !== undefined`. More info: [Inline If with Logical && Operator](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

Comment: FWIW I am not a fan of double-negating as it feels like a bug waiting to happen. For example, `0` (a zero integer) would return `false`, but `'0'` (a zero string) would return `true`. To me, it seems much better to be explicit and test for the case(s) you know about, like with `stringVariable !== undefined` in the above example.

Comment: Life saver. Thank you so much for figuring this out!

Comment: Is there a lint rule for this would be nice to be able to fix our warnings with --fix

Answer (score 9):

The problem for me with this error was that somehow I managed to end up with a `<View>` inside of `<Text>`. That was not very obvious because I had a `Button` component that was accepting some children wrapped in a `<Text>` and I was using some custom component for an `Icon` when instantiating Button. After a while somebody wrapped the `Icon` in a `<View>` to give it some padding and that caused the issue in the end.

It took some time to figure it out but in the end I solved it. 
It may differ from case to case but I hope my problem inspires you in your debugging session.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks, the problem is documented here http://facebook.github.io/react-native/releases/0.42/docs/text.html#nested-views-ios-only

Comment: React native is probably the worst thing that happened to apps.

Answer (score 2):

The `<Text>` node should not have any other child node in it. It might be that `<View>` is nested inside it or just any other component. So you can check for any child in the `<Text>` node and change your code. Also, this issue occurs only on Android.

Answer (score 2):

### Text rendered without a `<Text>` tag

Problem

```
<View> some text </View>
```

solution

```
<View>
   <Text> some text </Text>
</View>
```

this works with me

Answer (score 0):

I probably have the dumbest answer to this question, because its a problem with the basics, but I looked this one up because I accidently wrote a  outside the initial return statement.

so this:

```
return ( <View> <Text> example text </Text> ) </View>
```

should have been this:

```
return ( <View> <Text> exapmle text </Text> </View> )
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a simple space outside of a Text tag. Really hard to find.
So I had

```
<View>
  <View>
    <Text>Some text</Text>
  </View> <- Space here
</View>
```

To narrow it done I had to just comment out chunks until I figured it out.

Comment: You didn't close your child view

Comment: Just a typo. I have corrected that now thanks

Answer (score 0):

Always wrap plain text inside "< Text> </ Text>" if you are using "< View>".

example:
//Wrong way:
< View> Hello</ View>

//Right way:
< View>< Text> Hello </ Text></ View>

Comment: You could use formatting for the answer, so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using codestyle below svg along with  node the upper  node will not consider the  Component.

`<View> <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512"><path d="M495.9 166.6c3.2 8.7 .5 18.4-6.4 24.6l-43.3 39.4c1.1 8.3 1.7 16.8 1.7 25.4s-.6 17.1-1"/></svg> <Text>Privacy  settings</Text>  </View>`

Solution: Give new line in between  svg tag Text tag.
This will fix the issue.

Comment: I encourage you to update the format/layout of the XML file in order to improve the quality of your answer.